# defining the X values for a code

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, cdf

I have this task to create a script that acts similarly to normcdf on matlab.

```
       x=linspace(-5,5,1000); %values for x
       p= 1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp((-x.^2)/2); % THE PDF for the standard normal 
       t=cumtrapz(x,p); % the CDF for the standard normal distribution
       plot(x,t); %shows the graph of the CDF
```

The problem is when the `t` values are assigned to 1:1000 instead of -5:5 in increments. I want to know how to assign the correct x values, that is -5:5,1000 to the t values output? such as when I do `t(n)` I get the same result as `normcdf(n)`.

Just to clarify: the problem is I cannot simply say `t(-5)` and get result =1 as I would in `normcdf(1)` because the cumtrapz calculated values are assigned to x=1:1000 instead of -5 to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated answer

Ok, having read your comment; here is how to do what you want:

```
x = linspace(-5,5,1000);
p = 1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp((-x.^2)/2);
cdf = cumtrapz(x,p);

q = 3; % Query point
disp(normcdf(q)) % For reference
[~,I] = min(abs(x-q)); % Find closest index
disp(cdf(I)) % Show the value
```

Sadly, there is no matlab syntax which will do this nicely in one line, but if you abstract finding the closest index into a different function, you can do this:

```
cdf(findClosest(x,q))

function I = findClosest(x,q)
if q>max(x) || q<min(x)
    warning('q outside the range of x');
end
[~,I] = min(abs(x-q));
end
```

Also; if you are certain that the exact value of the query point `q` exists in `x`, you can just do

```
cdf(x==q);
```

But beware of floating point errors though. You may think that a certain range outght to contain a certain value, but little did you know it was different by a tiny roundoff erorr. You can see that in action for example here:

```
x1 = linspace(0,1,1000); % Range
x2 = asin(sin(x1)); % Ought to be the same thing
plot((x1-x2)/eps); grid on; % But they differ by rougly 1 unit of machine precision
```

## Old answer

As far as I can tell, running your code does reproduce the result of `normcdf(x)` well... If you want to do **exactly** what normcdf does them use `erfc`.

```
close all; clear; clc;

x = linspace(-5,5,1000);
cdf = normcdf(x); % Result of normcdf for comparison

%% 1 Trapezoidal integration of normal pd
p = 1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp((-x.^2)/2);
cdf1 = cumtrapz(x,p);

%% 2 But error function IS the integral of the normal pd
cdf2 = (1+erf(x/sqrt(2)))/2;

%% 3 Or, even better, use the error function complement (works better for large negative x)
cdf3 = erfc(-x/sqrt(2))/2;

fprintf('1: Mean error = %.2d\n',mean(abs(cdf1-cdf)));
fprintf('2: Mean error = %.2d\n',mean(abs(cdf2-cdf)));
fprintf('3: Mean error = %.2d\n',mean(abs(cdf3-cdf)));
plot(x,cdf1,x,cdf2,x,cdf3,x,cdf,'k--');
```

This gives me

```
1: Mean error = 7.83e-07
2: Mean error = 1.41e-17
3: Mean error = 00 <- Because that is literally what normcdf is doing
```

If your goal is not not to use predefined matlab funcitons, but instead to calculate the result numerically (i.e. calculate the error function) then it's an interesting challange which you can read about for example [here](https://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Sylvain.Chevillard/download/papers/ChevillardRevolRNC8.pdf) or in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-accurately-calculate-the-error-function-operatornameerfx-with-a-co) stats stackexchange post. Just as an example, the following piece of code calculates the error function by implementing eq. 2 form the first link:

```
nerf = @(x,n) (-1)^n*2/sqrt(pi)*x.^(2*n+1)./factorial(n)/(2*n+1);

figure(1); hold on;
temp = zeros(size(x)); p =[];
for n = 0:20
    temp = temp + nerf(x/sqrt(2),n);
    if~mod(n,3)
        p(end+1) = plot(x,(1+temp)/2);
    end
end
ylim([-1,2]);
title('\Sigma_{n=0}^{inf}  ( 2/sqrt(pi) ) \times ( (-1)^n x^{2*n+1} ) \div ( n! (2*n+1) )');
p(end+1) = plot(x,cdf,'k--');
legend(p,'n = 0','\Sigma_{n} 0->3','\Sigma_{n} 0->6','\Sigma_{n} 0->9',...
    '\Sigma_{n} 0->12','\Sigma_{n} 0->15','\Sigma_{n} 0->18','normcdf(x)',...
    'location','southeast');
grid on; box on;
xlabel('x'); ylabel('norm. cdf approximations');
```

[image: erfApprox]

Comment: I am not actually trying to get a 100% similar function, I chose -5:5 because that overs >95% of the cdf. but the problem is I cannot simply say cdf1(-5) and get result =1 as I would in normcdf(1) because the cumtrapz calculated values are assigned to x=1:1000 instead of -5 to 5

Answer (score 2):

[Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728589/7328782) suggests a way to find the nearest sample point. It is easier, IMO, to [interpolate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). Given `x` and `t` as defined in the question,

```
interp1(x,t,n)
```

returns the estimated value of the CDF at `x==n`, for whatever value of `n`. But note that, for values outside the computed range, it will extrapolate and produce unreliable values.

You can define an anonymous function that works like `normcdf`:

```
my_normcdf = @(n)interp1(x,t,n);

my_normcdf(-5)
```

Comment: @Marcin: sorry, I got the wrong name! Thanks for fixing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing x with 0.01 when you call cumtrapz. You can either use a vector or a scalar spacing for cumtrapz (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html), and this might solve your problem. Also, have you checked the original x-values? Is the problem with linspace (i.e. you are not getting the correct x vector), or with cumtrapz?

Comment: with cumtrapz, It assigned the y values to x=1:1000 instead of x=-5:5